# Trying to find an injective map between $(0,1)\to(0,1)\times(0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis

I know that their cardinalities are the same, so a $1-1$ map does exist, but i'm having a trouble trying to develop a proof.

Comment: Do you need to find an injective map or a bijective map?

Comment: Do you mean you're trying to find a surjection? For an injection just map $x\in (0,1)$ to $(x,1/2)$ in $(0,1)\times(0,1)$.

Comment: Just an injective map.

Comment: Then what about $f(x) = (x,x)$?

Comment: You need a *bijection* to prove identical cardinality.

Comment: @GregMartin, Could you please suggest a bijection?

Comment: Isnt a 1-1 map going both ways the only requirement according to the Schroeder-Bernstein Theorem?

Comment: one-to-one (=injective) maps _both_ ways is sufficient to prove equal cardinality. In this case finding an injective map (0,1) -> (0,1)x(0,1) is easier: two examples are given above in comments; this answers the title question. finding an injective map (0,1)x(0,1)->(0,1) is the trickier part.

Comment: @PabloTores Well, okay yes, if you do find an injecton for both dirrections you may infer that a bijection does exist.

Comment: The difficult thing is to find an injective map from $[0,1]^2$ to $[0,1]$....

Answer (score 4):

I'll do you one better; here's a bijective map. Every $x\in(0,1)$ can be uniquely represented as an infinite string of integers $\{0,1,\ldots,9\}$ (as a convention, terminating decimals like $0.25$ are represented as $0.24999\ldots$). The mapping then maps a number represented by the string $x_1x_2x_3\ldots$ to the ordered pair $(x_1x_3x_5\ldots,x_2x_4x_6\ldots)$. This mapping is injective because only one string of integers can map to one ordered pair. It's clearly surjective also.

Comment: wouldn't .999... not work though?

Comment: .999... is actually equal to 1, so it's not an element of the ordered pair. So it's not in the codomain of the mapping.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Consider that *every* real number in the interval $(0,1)$ has a unique *decimal representation*.   Can you one-to-one map these to a unique pair of decimal representations in the interval $(0,1)^2$ ?

Comment: Don't some numbers (some terminating decimals) in that interval have *two* decimal representations? [I guess that only happens for countably many so maybe doesn't matter...]

Comment: ... yes... indeed